# Set Envelop's "From" field

Tags: rest, docusignapi

I am creating an envelop Via Rest but I want the From of the envelop to be somebody else. It seems like it's not possible to create an envelop on behalf of another account.

Has anyone experience something similar?

Answer (score 0):

Correct, the "from" field cannot be set in the API directly.
It is derived from your access token you obtained to make API calls.
This access token represents some user in DocuSign, that user makes the API calls - therefore, that user is the sender ("from" them the envelopes come).

One way to "send on behalf of someone" is to use [JWT authentication](https://developers.docusign.com/platform/auth/jwt/). With JWT, you provide the **userId** for the user that will be impersonated. That user will be then the "from" for your envelope. If you want to send multiple envelopes and wish each of them had a different "from" field, you would have to obtain multiple access tokens with different userIds.

Lastly note that JWT requires the user to agree (consent) to you impersonating them. This consent is only required once and then your integration is authorized forever (the reason is that I wouldn't like your code to be able to send out envelopes coming from me without my consent, right?)